# Woocommerce Rest Api (2.6 & later) - 401 error

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I would like to use Woocommerce with Rest API.

So, my process :

1. activate REST API in woocommerce's settings.
2. Generate keys for an user.
3. Try to authentificate me over HTTP.

The third step works with this:
https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce

But, I cannot get data, like products.

**My code:**

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://delphes.local',
    'ck_ee31d8082f5b6213b369ef5fb1d4f387e0241840',
    'cs_479ce18567c180263f130072dea082b52872e6e9',
[
    'wp_api' => true,
    'version' => 'wc/v1',
    'verify_ssl'    =>  false,
]
);
var_dump($woocommerce);
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;
try {
    $results = $woocommerce->get('products');
    // Last request data.
    $lastRequest = $woocommerce->http->getRequest();
    $lastRequest->getUrl(); // Requested URL (string).
    $lastRequest->getMethod(); // Request method (string).
    $lastRequest->getParameters(); // Request parameters (array).
    $lastRequest->getHeaders(); // Request headers (array).
    $lastRequest->getBody(); // Request body (JSON).

    // Last response data.
    $lastResponse = $woocommerce->http->getResponse();
    $lastResponse->getCode(); // Response code (int).
    $lastResponse->getHeaders(); // Response headers (array).
    $lastResponse->getBody(); // Response body (JSON).
    echo "ok";
    var_dump($results);
    var_dump($lastRequest);
    var_dump($lastResponse);
}catch (HttpClientException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage()); // Error message.
    var_dump($e->getRequest()); // Last request data.
    var_dump($e->getResponse()); // Last response data.
}
```

**And the response:**

```
object(Automattic\WooCommerce\Client)[2906]
 public 'http' => 
object(Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient)[2907]
  protected 'ch' => null
  protected 'url' => string 'http://delphes.local/wp-json/wc/v1/' (length=35)
  protected 'consumerKey' => string 'ck_ee31d8082f5b6213b369ef5fb1d4f387e0241840' (length=43)
  protected 'consumerSecret' => string 'cs_479ce18567c180263f130072dea082b52872e6e9' (length=43)
  protected 'options' => 
    object(Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Options)[2908]
      private 'options' => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
  private 'request' => null
  private 'response' => null
  private 'responseHeaders' => null

 string 'cURL Error: Operation timed out after 15008 milliseconds with 0 bytes received' (length=78)

object(Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request)[2909]
  private 'url' => string 'http://delphes.local/wp-json/wc/v1/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_ee31d8082f5b6213b369ef5fb1d4f387e0241840&oauth_nonce=fbfd6ee91b9586fa47816b924c79c1c4b1bf3d5c&oauth_signature=PXhShXEu0bgVQuo8pNkLKREUvGcwUyCl593osEF0Akk%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1475658731' (length=284)
  private 'method' => string 'GET' (length=3)
  private 'parameters' => 
array (size=5)
  'oauth_consumer_key' => string 'ck_ee31d8082f5b6213b369ef5fb1d4f387e0241840' (length=43)
  'oauth_nonce' => string 'fbfd6ee91b9586fa47816b924c79c1c4b1bf3d5c' (length=40)
  'oauth_signature' => string 'PXhShXEu0bgVQuo8pNkLKREUvGcwUyCl593osEF0Akk=' (length=44)
  'oauth_signature_method' => string 'HMAC-SHA256' (length=11)
  'oauth_timestamp' => int 1475658731
  private 'headers' => 
array (size=3)
  'Accept' => string 'application/json' (length=16)
  'Content-Type' => string 'application/json' (length=16)
  'User-Agent' => string 'WooCommerce API Client-PHP/1.1.1' (length=32)
  private 'body' => string '' (length=0)


object(Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response)[2911]
  private 'code' => int 0
  private 'headers' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
  private 'body' => boolean false
```

When I use this URL: http://delphes.local/wp-json/wc/v1/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_ee31d8082f5b6213b369ef5fb1d4f387e0241840&oauth_nonce=fbfd6ee91b9586fa47816b924c79c1c4b1bf3d5c&oauth_signature=PXhShXEu0bgVQuo8pNkLKREUvGcwUyCl593osEF0Akk%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1475658731

I have the same response with this at the end:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\delphes\wp-content\themes\delphes\functions.php:49) in D:\delphes\wp-includes\rest-api\class-wp-rest-server.php on line 1196

AND

> {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources","data":{"status":401}}

I tried too in node.js with this: `woocommerce-api (npm package)`

With this package, I cannot initialize class by require (by import or require).
I have this error :

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "net"
>
> => in cookies.js:32 from package "tough-cookie".

After installation of this missing package, it's a new error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../package.json"
>
> in cookies.js:38 ..........

So, I have given up this way.

Now, I'm staying with Automattic.

Maybe, it's a problem with my `vhost`, or my `htaccess`?

I searched for a long time before to write this question.

What do you think about this `error 401`?

Have a good day for a nice community :)

Comment: Fixed ! :) - I'm a newbie with oauth ....

Comment: You should post the answer...

Comment: Oauth cannot run in a local without online dns. I tried in my vps, with an online dns, without apache authentification and it's running ! ;)